# Create a voice record reactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, voice-recording

I am trying to add voice record feature in a chat application ,I have tried this package
**react-mic** it work fine and it give me this data when I stopped the record
[image]

I want now to send this as a binary file to the backend I have tried this

```
  let name = `test.ogg`
  let lastModified = new Date()
  let file = new File([{...audioData.blob,name,lastModified}],name,{
    type:"audio/ogg"
  })
```

but it didn't work as expected It change it to binary but it is not a valid file because when I try to change it and played it in the browser it didn't work ,I have read alot of articles but nothing help

and for the method I used I have follow this article
https://pqina.nl/blog/convert-a-blob-to-a-file-with-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

I will put this here in case someone want to do the same thing

After trying alot with different packages I used the **MediaStream Recording** api it is really easy to use and it give me the result I want

This is the url for the documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API